How to increase the size of the Stripe Payment container and not lose quality

original css
after applying width property
my intended goal but better quality (it doesnt show it but the quality was horrible) 

How can I increase the container size, while keeping the same ratio and not losing quality.
So, my orginal css made the container really small in the mobile web-viewpoint, but when I tried to increase the width of the container, all it did was add some blank space in between, making it difficult to see anything (the font size was really small). So the next thing I did was use the scale() property and margin-top, and that worked but the quality was incredibly low (like if you tried zooming in you could see the difference between the scaled container and a regular container I made) .

I'd suggest you to increase the width and height of the container instead of doing a scale transformation. If you want to increase the font size, use the Appearance API.
